# Two questions concerning the position of the command `\lstset` of the Listings pack­age

Tags: listings

1. I am a newcomer to Latex. Page 12 of the pack­age doc­u­men­ta­tion(http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) has the following sentences:

   > All parameters set via `\lstset` keep their values up to the
   >   end of the current environment or group. Afterwards the previous values are restored.

   I have tried putting `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}` somewhere in a source file. After compiling, all subsequent listings in the document are typeset in typewriter font. Hence I can not figure out what does "up to the end of the current environment or group. Afterwards the previous values are restored." want to tell me. Could anyone give me an example?
2. Are there any differences between placing `\lstset` in the preamble and just after `\begin{document}`? That is, for example,

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,numbers=left}
   \begin{document}
   ```

   and

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \begin{document}
   \lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,numbers=left}
   ```

I would appreciate any help with this situation.

Comment: If you use `\lstset` inside a `\begin{}...\end{}` environment (not `lstlistings` of course!) the settings with `\lstset` only 'live' as long the environment is active, or similarly, in `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair. Any change in there is not visible outside, i.e. the settings outside of such a group or environment are not changed. If you use it outside a group (or environment, the changes count, however

Comment: And please, do not post such fragments only. And I would also not link the ctan archive of such a commercial site like mackichan! [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org) is the name of the game ;-)

Comment: And it does not make any difference, before or after `\begin{document}`, as long as you don't change it again in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends wheter or not the command `lstset` is used inside of an environment (like center, a theorem environment, etc).
In this case, all listing inside the environment will be affected by the style change, but the listing after the environment will not.
Note that if you want to change the style of only one listing, it can be achideved using brackets juste after `\begin{lstlisting}`

See for example the following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{thm}
My theorem
\begin{lstlisting}
A first listing
Without number lines
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,numbers=left}
\begin{lstlisting}
A second listing
Without number lines
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
A third listing
Also with number lines
\end{lstlisting}


\end{thm}

\begin{lstlisting}
A fourth listing
Without number lines
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{center}
I can also change style for only one listing !
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,numbers=left]
A fifth listing
With numer lines
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
A sixth listing
Regular style
\end{lstlisting}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Any use of `\lstset` outside of such an environment should affect all the listings in the document.